# Lighthouse shows Does not respond with a 200 when offline in pwa but offline mode works

Tags: laravel-5, webpack, progressive-web-apps, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

**Quick question:**

While the browser identifies my application as a valid PWA, as well as shows the install popup on the mobile browser. When it is audited in lighthouse, it shows Does not respond with a 200 when offline. I have validated that my app shell is cached from application(screenshots attached).

**Details and Background:** 
I have built PWA on laravel using js and jquery. For asset compiling, I am using laravel mix and for PWA framework, I am using workbox. Also just to be clear I am not using any SPA framework/library .

In short I have built a custom spa using simpler components.

For PWA part this I am using workbox along with laravel mix. 
Here are my service worker, manifest.json and mix file. note that I use sw.js and generate prod-sw.js using laravel-mix. This prod-sw.js is used in production

webpack.mix.js

```
require('laravel-mix-versionhash');
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

const workboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
        publicPath: ''
    }, 
    plugins: [
        new workboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
            swSrc: 'sw.js', // more control over the caching
            swDest: 'prod-sw.js', // the service-worker file name
            importsDirectory: 'service-worker', // have a dedicated folder for sw files
            exclude: [/\.map$/, /mix-manifest\.json$/, /mix\..*\.js$/, /manifest\.json$/, /service-worker\.js$/, /OneSignalSDKWorker\.js$/],
            include: [/template\..*\.html$/, /\.js$/, /app\..*\.css$/, /logo.png$/],
            templatedUrls: {
              '/pwa': 'version-' + process.env.MIX_APP_VERSION,
            },
        })
    ],
})

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/homepage.scss', 'public/css/')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/amp.scss', 'public/css/')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss','public/css/');

if (mix.inProduction()){
    mix.versionHash();
}else{
    mix.sourceMaps();
}
```

sw.js

```
var version = 123;

workbox.core.setLogLevel(workbox.core.LOG_LEVELS.silent);
workbox.skipWaiting();
workbox.clientsClaim();

const precacheController = new workbox.precaching.PrecacheController();


// Cache all scripts and stylesheets using an extension whitelist
workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('.(?:css|html|ico)$'),
    workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
        cacheName: 'static-resources',
        /* plugins: [
        new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
            maxEntries: 35,
            maxAgeSeconds:1*24*60*60,
        }),
        ], */
    })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('.*(?:pwa\.|vendors\.).*\.js$'),
    workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
        cacheName: 'js-cache-' + version,
        plugins: [
        new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
            maxAgeSeconds: 8*24*60*60,
        }),
        ], 
    })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute('/pwa',
    workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
        cacheName: 'html-cache-' + version,
    })
);


workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest);
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "short_name": "Example",
    "name": "Example",
    "description": "Example App Description",
    "gcm_sender_id": "1234567890",
    "start_url" : "/pwa",
    "display": "standalone",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "theme_color": "#FFFFFF",
    "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "https://cdn.example.com/assets/icons/icon-48x48.png",
            "sizes": "48x48",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ]
}
```

A snapshot of manifest file, cache storage and lighthouse report is attached for your reference. [Manifest.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpvaD.png), [Cache Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKqFo.png) and [Lighthouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEDXA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but without providing `templateUrl` property.
It works offline for me just in devTools but not fully offline and lighthouse has given the same results as yours.